# Reactjs app making requests to Django which exists on different domain

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm trying to make a request from my reactjs app existing on "localhost:3000" to my django living in "localhost:8000"

I was expecting some authentication token in header to passed along with the request, but it's not the case. The request seems to be stripped and the token is nowhere to be found. Unless I pass the token in the url as a parameter (which exposes the token that can be decoded. I don't like it), I can't seem to be able to get the token in any way.

so my questions:

1. is this CORS issue? My understanding is that CORS usually deals with javascripts only, and Django already has the middleware to deal with this.
2. I'm currently using a GET as method. Does using a POST help in this case? How would the reactjs script be written? Currently it's just a `href` attached to a `NavItem`

and ultimately:

3. How do I pass the token from reactjs to django?

Comment: what error do you get?, probably is the CORS causing the error, what token do you mean?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I have a token that contains info of username and permissions from Auth0. This is acquired when I log in on the reactjs side. The error code is 403 as the permission check on Django side cannot find such token. The django request is then using `AnonymousUser`, which cannot and should not access what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can perform the [implicit grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant) on the front-end and then [configure the Django API in Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/apis#how-to-configure-an-api-in-auth0) and specify its identifier in the `audience` parameter. This would grant you an `access token` which you could then use against your API. Your API would then verify the token and check the `audience` is correct. (This has a good overview of the process https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/implicit and then with the API https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api)

Basically what we can do is when Auth0 authenticates the user it redirects the user to the app with an `access token`, and optionally an `id token`, in the hash fragment of the URI. We can extract that and use the token to call the API on behalf of the user.

So, after we have [created the API in Auth0][3, [defined the endpoints][3](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/part-3#define-the-api-endpoints), and [secured the endpoints](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/part-3#secure-the-endpoints) we can [call the API](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/part-3#call-the-api) (by sending the `access token` in an Authorization header using the Bearer scheme).

If you have any Auth0 specific question please feel free to join over in [community.auth0.com](https://community.auth0.com/) you may have better luck finding help/solutions.

Answer (score -1):

The 403 error is telling you that the request is not being processed because something is stopping from process that request 403: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated

As you said probably because the CORS, try to follow the guide bellow of how to install Django-cors

https://github.com/mbrochh/django-graphql-apollo-react-demo#add-jwt-authentication-to-django

Comment: No, the 403 is generated by me as I want to check the auth token. If I fake the token and inject it into the request, the process goes through. All still leads back to the fact that I'm missing this token in my header

Comment: @JChao the request can go through but it doesn't mean that it has been authorized, did you add CORS to your project?